# JSP requestDispacthing

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have two JSP pages. In first page I have given fields to fill personal details and I have written request.getRequestDispatcher("second.jsp") and  forwarded the the request. But When I run the "first.jsp" on server in eclipse, it is directly going to "second.jsp" but in URL it is shopwing "first.jsp". What might be the problem?

**First.jsp**

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<h2>Enter Your Personal Details</h2>
<form action="personal.jsp" method="get">
<table>
<tr><td>Name:      </td><td>   <input type="text" name="name" /><br /><br /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Email-ID:     </td><td><input type="text" name="email" /><br /><br /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Date Of Birth:</td><td><input type="text" name="dob" /><br /><br /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password: </td><td><input type="text" name="pass" /><br /><br /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Age: </td><td><input type="text" name="age" /><br /><br /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
<%!
String uname=null,pass=null,email=null; 
String age=null,dob = null;
%>
<%
uname= request.getParameter("name");
session.setAttribute("username",uname);
pass= request.getParameter("pass");
session.setAttribute("password",pass);
age = request.getParameter("age");
session.setAttribute("age",age);
email = request.getParameter("email");
session.setAttribute("email",email);
dob = request.getParameter("dob");
session.setAttribute("dob",dob);
response.sendRedirect("academic.jsp");
%>
</body>
</html>
```

**Second.jsp**

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<br>
<h2>Enter Your Academic Details</h2>
<form action="academic.jsp" method="get">
<table><tr><td>
MID:       </td><td> <input type="text" name="mid" /><br /><br /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Marks:      </td><td>   <input type="text" name="marks" /><br /><br /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Salary:     </td><td><input type="text" name="salary" /><br /><br /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Stream:</td><td><select name="stream"><option>Java</option><option>dotNET</option><option>Testing</option></select><br /><br /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" /></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
<%
out.println(session.getAttribute("name"));
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you put your code fragment?

Comment: @sonic there's no need to add code, that's how a forward works

Comment: ya. but i believe his problem is that user is not able to fill the form. It is redirecting to second.jsp before that. I may be wrong.

Comment: based on OP's comment on the current answer, that seems to be the problem. But even the worse problem is the usage of scriptlets to accomplish this that leads to the lack of knowledge of the technology =\

Answer (score 1):

You need to do `response.sendRedirect()` to make the effect in url.

```
request#forward
```

Silently passes the control to your another resource,And happens on server side,browser doesn't know about it.

[Forward():](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/RequestDispatcher.html#forward%28javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse%29)

> For a RequestDispatcher obtained via getRequestDispatcher(), the ServletRequest object has its path elements and parameters adjusted to match the path of the target resource.

[sendRedirect()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#sendRedirect%28java.lang.String%29)

> Sends a temporary redirect response to the client using the specified redirect location URL and clears the buffer.

Highlighting Luggis comment,that move your business logic to `Controller` and try to avoid `scriplets` too if possible.

Though,it is not recommended,If you want to change the URL and still want to access the data in second page,one possibility is that put data in session and access in second jsp.

Comment: That might work if OP's not setting any request attributes. It will be better explain what's the meaning of this instead suggesting plain redirection to handle all the navigations

Comment: I am not getting using response.sendRedirect() method. Actually after getting all personal details in "first.jsp" and then storing those details in session object and then I want to redirect to "second.jsp", to fetch some more details in "second.jsp". But When I run "first.jsp" it is immediately redirecting to "second.jsp".

Comment: @BabannaDuggani still the data in the session exists,don't worry.You can access it.

Comment: @BabannaDuggani this is due to you having a direct call of `request.getRequestDispatcher("second.jsp").forward(request, response)` probably in a scriptlet (which is **very bad practice**). All your navigations should be handled in servlets or another controller classes.

Comment: *one possibility is that put data in session and access in second jsp* if you will do that, remove the data from session after its consumption

Comment: Exactly,remove those attributes after that usage.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is generated because you have a direct call of forward method in a scriptlet, this might look like this

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("second.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

By your question edit, this is generating the problem:

```
response.sendRedirect("academic.jsp");
```

Note that using scriptlets is **highly discouraged**.

Make sure all your data processing and navigation is handled in a [Servlet](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135475.html) or another controller classes provided by a MVC framework like JSF managed beans or Spring MVC `@Controller` decorated classes.

More info:

- [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1065197)
- [StackOverflow's Servlet wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info), here you can find a real world basic example about how to handle data processing and manipulation from a view to a servlet and then navigating to another view.

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem lies in `first.jsp` line `response.sendRedirect("academic.jsp");` which is inside a [JSP Declaration](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaos.html) and not JSP Scriptlet, as per the doc `variables and methods in JSP declarations become declarations in the JSP page’s servlet class` which explains why when  you hit the `first.jsp` its getting redirected to another page without any action and as other suggested its not advisable to use JSP scriptlets, or declarations in your JSP.